# How to sort a list of list based on the same set value in the list?

Tags: python, list, sorting, set

```
a = [['a', 'b'], ['b'], ['b', 'a']]
```

Because the 1st and 3rd element are the same, if they are converted to a set, I want to sort the list 'a' so that any two elements with the same set value would be next to each other. For the example above, the sorted result would be:

```
a = [['a', 'b'], ['b', 'a'], ['b']]
```

OR

```
a = [['b'], ['a', 'b'], ['b', 'a']]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `list(set(x))` as your key. Since the ordering this imposes would be a bit arbitrary, you could add `sorted` to the mix:

```
a = [['a', 'b'], ['b'], ['b', 'a']]
a.sort(key=lambda x: sorted(set(x)))
```

Note that this is not the same as using `key=sorted` because of how duplicate elements are handled.

Comment: Glad you like it. It's the most straightforward interpretation of your question I could think of.

Answer (score 3):

One way using `hash` with `frozenset`:

```
sorted(a, key=lambda x: hash(frozenset(x)))
```

Output:

```
[['b'], ['a', 'b'], ['b', 'a']]
```

Tested with more elemenets:

```
a = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b'], 
     ['b'], ['b', 'd'], ['b', 'a'], 
     ['a', 'c'], ['b', 'c', 'a']]
sorted(a, key=lambda x: hash(frozenset(x)))
```

Output:

```
[['a', 'c'],
 ['a', 'b', 'c'],
 ['b', 'c', 'a'],
 ['b'],
 ['b', 'd'],
 ['a', 'b'],
 ['b', 'a']]
```